# RIA services Out/Ref parameters

Tags: wcf-ria-services, ref, out, param

I m new RIA services. I have to make two service call to validate two conditions and I m trying to use out param to know outcome of the validation function say output -1 will denote first validation failed, output -2 will denote second validation failed and if 0 everything is in order. How to include output/reference parameter in RIA service method.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can not add out/ref parameters in RIA sevice methods, which are actually WCF methods.
instead, you can create a class that includes a property for validation outcome along with other properties, then return that class from the method.